# How to test respond_with when there is no instance variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

I have simple API controller with `show` action:

```
def show
  respond_with(current_api_user)
end
```

where `current_api_user` is method provided by Doorkeeper gem. Recently I have tested such cases with `assigns` method, but there is no instance variable assignment in this controller. Is there some ready-to-use test helper that mocks controllers' `respond_with`? Should I mock it by myself?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered the same problem. Simply pass in `nil` in place of an instance variable, such as:

```
respond_with(nil, current_api_user)
```